# change view colour on tap then back to original colour

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to use UITapGestureRecognizer to change a UIView color when the view is tapped, then back to the original white color when space outside the UIView is tapped. I can get the UIView to change colors but I cannot get it to change back to white color.

```
  // viewDidLoad
let tapGestureRegonizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(mortgagePenaltyVC.viewCellTapped(recognizer:)))
    tapGestureRegonizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    mortgageLenerViewCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRegonizer)

@objc func viewCellTapped (recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("label Tapped")


    mortgageLenerViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray



    }
```

Comment: use same tap for self.view (for tapping in outside the view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `touchesBegan` method to get the touch outside of view like below

This code works for me...

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: mortgageLenerViewCell) else { return }
    if !labelToClick.frame.contains(location) {
        print("Tapped outside the view")
        mortgageLenerViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }else {
        print("Tapped inside the view")
        mortgageLenerViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
}
```

here `labelToClick` is the label on which you want to click & `mortgageLenerViewCell` is the superview of `labelToClick`

Feel free to ask for any query...

Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work! My goal is when the user taps the view it turns light grey. When they tap somewhere outside the view it turns back to the original color, which is white.

Comment: is 'mortgageLenerViewCell' is uiview or uitableviewcell??

Comment: check my update .. you won't even need any gesture for click on the label gesture.

Comment: Thank you once again. Its the UIView named "mortgageLenerViewCell" that when tapped changes the color. There is no label. I changed "labelToClick" to equal the UIView name but it does not work and sit does not work for me. Could it be a simulator issue?

Comment: just replace labelToClick to mortgageLenerViewCell.. It will solve your problem

Comment: I did that and it did not help. Maybe it's an issue with the outlet. @IBOutlet weak var mortgageLenerViewCell: DesignableView! The DesignableView is I created to add bottom borders.

Comment: I think you have inserted some kind of subview or layer to the original view to change the design.. check whats going on in UI by debugging View Hierarchy...

Comment: I figured out the problem The UIView is on a scrollView. If I delete the scroll view everything works. But I need to keep the scroll view. Any thoughts how to fix this issue.